# Loading string data from table gets parsed as Date on Chrome - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using a datatable as the source for a Highcharts graph, I have a table where the first column (in highcharts it represents the x-axis labels) gets parsed as Dates on Chrome, I have copied the exact same example they have on their site and just changed the string inside the th tags like so:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jane</th>
            <th>John</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Base 0</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Base 1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Base 2</th>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Base 3</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Base 4</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above example can be seen on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yq8tz63/2/

I have also modified the th tags to include single and double qoutes ('Base 4'): https://jsfiddle.net/1yq8tz63/4/

Is it a browser or coding error?

Answer (score 0):

It does not properly understand what type you are using for the x-axis.

You can specify it like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yq8tz63/8/)):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
}
```

It will then treat the table headers as categories (text), instead of some index/date.